# tabMode="scrollable" not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am using the TabLayout from Android Design support library. I am using material design theme. Below is the code

activity_scrollable_Tab.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

scrollableTabActivity.java

```
public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        .....
        adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "TEN");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Tab scrolling is working in Lollipop. But the same code is not working on Kitkat and Jelly bean devices. On Kitkat and Jelly bean device I face two problem,

1. When I scroll the Tab, Tab is scrolling along with page navigation in Jellybean and kitkat devices, but in Lollipop Tab alone gets scroll and it is working file. For eg: if 1,2,3..10 are the Tab and if I scroll the Tab, it scroll and for each scroll the Layout gets navigated. If I scroll, Tab gets navigate to 2nd Tab and then 3rd and so on.
2. Up navigation is not working in Jellybean and Kitkat devices. If I swipe the Toolbar, Tab scrolling is happening with page navigation (above-mentioned issue).

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem and in which portion I need to check and sort it. I can send APK file if provide me the email for a better understanding of the problem.

I am new to android, need some help to fix this.

Comment: I solved it by adding xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" for Tab layout "activity_scrollable_Tab.xml".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should set that tab mode programmatically? Try to call `setTabMode` method on `TabLayaut` instance 
`tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);`

I don't know why it doesn't work for you, but I tested these modes few weeks ago, and for me scrollable mode worked on all Android versions.

Also check if you use the latest version of Design Support Library, maybe you use some previous bugged version?

Answer (score 2):

To make Tab scrollable work in kitkat and Jelly bean devices you can refer this tutorial

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html

Google docs is also there for this
https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

It is well tested and working for me on all devices

Comment: In kitkat and Jelly bean devices the TabLayout is scrolling and taking me to another layout. If i am scrolling the Tab alone, in lollipop the Tab itself scroll but in other devices the Tab scroll and the it navigate to other page. For eg: if 1,2..10 is the Tab name and if i scroll these in lollipop Tab itself just scroll it won't navigate to other Layout and in other devices the Tab scroll and it navigate to 2nd Tab then 3rd Tab and so on. Any idea what might be the problem.

Comment: I have updated my source code. I am following the code from http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ , the sample is from Android studio and i copied and pasted the file from the Android studio and created in Eclipse, because my project is in eclipse.

Comment: Any idea what could be the problem and where to check the code.

Comment: I will try with that link.

Comment: I solved it by adding xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" for Tab layout "activity_scrollable_Tab.xml".

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

My case is some thing different which is not solved by most of the answers i tried.

The answer is add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in your `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

I am posting the complete code here,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

After adding `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in my TabLayout xml file, Tab scroll function working fine in Jelly bean, Kitkat and lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below xml for your *TabLayout*.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
app:tabMode="scrollable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your FragmentPagerAdapter looks a little weird, why are you adding your fragments to a List? Have you tried adding

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

before

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

on setupViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

Just a warmly reminder to beginner like me, it needs many items(more than the size of screen width) to make it scrollable, so don't expect it able to scroll if you test with only two items, and this is not the same thing like  "scroll to switch tab" you might looking for, tabMode="scrollable" only scroll without switch.