# Customize SlidingTabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs, android-icons

I'm using a **SlidingTabLayout** in my android application by referring this link http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

And my requirement is like the below image which i have post.

I am not able to tag SlidingTabLayout as my reputation does not fullfil the requirement.

[image]

As I am new to this whole setup, I'd appreciate if you'd post proper code with an explaination.

Comment: for sliding tab layout you can follow my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925636/tabmode-scrollable-not-working/32926361#32926361

Comment: @Awadesh my focus is to design the tabs as i have posted.How to put looks exactly like the above image in tabs.

Comment: Alternatively, you may consider to use this library : https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

In order to inflate the tabs with custom view , in file SlidingTablayout.java there is a method

```
 public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}
```

Using this method you can inflate your tabs view.
For more details you can follow this also

[Android SlidingTabLayout with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420293/android-slidingtablayout-with-icons)

In order to set different custom views in different tabs you can modify the method populateTabStrip() like this

```
public void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;

    tabView =     LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, mTabStrip,false);

        ImageView iconImageView = (ImageView)   tabView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_icon);
          iconImageView.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(getIconResourceArray()[i]));

        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried as above you mentioned. I have 5 no. of tabs then how to handle those in setCustomTabView()? I am not able to do this.

Comment: @PRB i have updated my answer, please go in detail of the given link atleast for once, you will find the solution for sure :)

Comment: @Awadesh-- I have one query.. is it possible to customize TabLayout? Not SlidingTabLayout.

Comment: @PRB yes you can. So SlidingTabLayout is not working , If you have any doubt please ask :)

Comment: no not yet. :(.... I am not able to set icons for different tabs.
where to set the IconResourceArray() and in populateTabStrip() I am getting that.Like this...
iconImageView.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(getIconResourceArray()[i]));

Comment: okk please see this answer , there is everything http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1772823+[android-tabstrip], If you have any doubt please ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93613/discussion-between-awadesh-and-prb).